# PowerShell - piped property not not working as I had hoped

Tags: powershell

I am a little new to PowerShell, so this is probably a basic question.

I have written a small one-liner to remove the first 97 lines from the top of each text file in a directory.

The script works in as far as removing the line, but the new file created at the end doesn't have the name I expected.  Here is the script:

```
Get-ChildItem | ForEach-Object {Get-Content $_.PSPath | Select -Skip 97 | Set-Content "Edited-$_.PSChildName" }
```

The original file is called:
    file.txt
What I expect the new file to be called is:
    Edited-file.txt
The file actually comes out as:
    Edited-file.txt.PSChildName

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I think you want `Set-Content "Edited-$($_.PSChildName)"`. The `$()` allows you to interpolate expressions into strings e.g. "abc$(2+2)" returns the string "abc4".